# How can I merge records in my SET?

Tags: merge, set, duplicate-management

My code is adding contacts in a loop. The issue I am trying to solve is that if I get more than 1 contact record with the same email address, I need to modify a custom field on the contact record instead of adding the record to the loop.

For example: This code has two contact records with the exact same details except for the contact_type field. In such a scenario, I would merge the two records and update the contact_type_field to "Customer Contact, Site Contact".

**How do I approach this problem?** Ideally I would like the feed itself to change so that I don't have to deal with this. At any time, I get between 10 - 15 contacts in a feed for an account. Also I need to insert all of them in one single command. I have explored the idea of upserting one contact at a time and then re-querying the database. This just leads to hitting governor limits.

```
List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
Set<Contact> setEmails = new Set<Contact>();
Contact c = new Contact();
c.Email = 'anish.giri@mailinator.com';
c.LastName = 'Giri';
c.FirstName = 'Anish';
c.AccountId = '0011900000BjqPR';
c.Contact_Type__c = 'Customer Contact';
conList.add(c);
setEmails.add(c);

c = new Contact();
c.Email = 'anish.giri@mailinator.com';
c.LastName = 'Giri';
c.FirstName = 'Anish';
c.AccountId = '0011900000BjqPR';
c.Contact_Type__c = 'Site Contact';
listEmails.Add(c.Email);
conList.add(c);
setEmails.add(c);

System.Debug('Set Contents: ' + setEmails);
System.Debug('List Contents: ' + conList);
```

Comment: is the code above the prod code or the testmethod code? If the latter, what does the prod code look like?

Comment: The prod code looks different. This is a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with two problems here. Grouping by email address and then merging data between duplicates.

Using a `Map<String, Contact>` where the `String` is the contact's email address is a great way to identify duplicates as you can use the `Map.containsKey(string)` to figure out if the map's keyset already contains the contact's email address.

For the example below, I'm introducing another contact which won't be a duplicate to the two you've got listed.

---

Sample data to be scrubbed for duplicates by the code below

```
// List of source contacts
List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

// first contact
Contact c = new Contact();
c.Email = 'anish.giri@mailinator.com';
c.LastName = 'Giri';
c.FirstName = 'Anish';
c.AccountId = '0011900000BjqPR';
c.Contact_Type__c = 'Customer Contact';
contactList.add(c);

// second contact, unrelated
Contact c1 = new Contact();
c1.Email = 'bobby.tables@example.com';
c1.LastName = 'Tables';
c1.FirstName = 'Bobby';
c1.AccountId = 'some id value'; // don't hardcode id values
c1.Contact_Type__c = 'Customer Contact';
contactList.add(c1);

// third contact. Will be duplicate via matching email address
Contact c2 = new Contact();
c2.Email = 'anish.giri@mailinator.com';
c2.LastName = 'Giri';
c2.FirstName = 'Anish';
c2.AccountId = '0011900000BjqPR';
c2.Contact_Type__c = 'Site Contact';
contactList.add(c2);
```

---

Code to find duplicates by email address

```
// Use a Map keyed/grouped by email address to easily find duplicates
Map<String, Contact> contactMap = new Map<String, Contact>();

// iterate the source contact list and find duplicates
for (Contact c : contactList) {

    // check for a duplicate by email address, key in the map == duplicate
    if (contactMap.containsKey(c.Email)) {

        // do not add 'c' to the Map in this case
        // this is a duplicate to a contact already found in the list
        // merge your field values as needed

        Contact originalContact = contactMap.get(c.Email);

        // use 'c' and 'originalContact'
        // choose how to merge data onto the 'originalContact' record's fields
        // originalContact.fieldName += c.fieldName; (or similar)

    } else {
        // not a duplicate, add Contact to the map under the key of its email address
        contactMap.put(c.Email, c);
    }
}

// perform DML on the records that are in the map
if (contactMap.isEmpty()) {

    // get the list of Contact records from the map and insert them
    insert contactMap.values();
}
```